# how to retrieve URL's of video segments from .mpd manifest file in python?

Tags: python, streaming, video-streaming, mpeg-dash

I need to retrieve urls of all segments(streams) of a video from a .mpd file. I am not able to figure out how we can generate url's from .mpd file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <MPD mediaPresentationDuration="PT2H34M47.960S" minBufferTime="PT3.00S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011" type="static" xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xmlns:cenc="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013">
    <!-- Created with Bento4 mp4-dash.py, VERSION=1.7.0-613 -->
    <Period>
      <!-- Video -->
      <AdaptationSet maxHeight="360" maxWidth="640" mimeType="video/mp4" minHeight="180" minWidth="320" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1">
        <!-- MPEG Common Encryption -->
        <ContentProtection cenc:default_KID="7cac8db7-a352-568e-9c06-e5d26147da86" schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc"/>
        <!-- Widevine -->
        <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed">
          <cenc:pssh>AAAAdHBzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAAFQSEOHBxsC86lMVrHwU7a6LubISEHysjbejUlaOnAbl0mFH2oYSEAvHADm/u1gUlLVvSEU2ha8aDHNvdGFsYXBhbGF5YSIIMTAwMTczMzdI49yVmwY=</cenc:pssh>
        </ContentProtection>
        <SegmentTemplate duration="3000" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4?svdghahgdahd hvdhvhavdha" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s?agsdjsgajfjagfjafjag fgaj" startNumber="1" timescale="1000"/>
        <Representation bandwidth="79914" codecs="avc1.42C00C" frameRate="25" height="180" id="video/1" scanType="progressive" width="320"/>
        <Representation bandwidth="137430" codecs="avc1.42C01E" frameRate="25" height="360" id="video/2" scanType="progressive" width="640"/>
        <Representation bandwidth="265383" codecs="avc1.42C01E" frameRate="25" height="360" id="video/3" scanType="progressive" width="640"/>
        <Representation bandwidth="521314" codecs="avc1.42C01E" frameRate="25" height="360" id="video/4" scanType="progressive" width="640"/>
        <Representation bandwidth="777245" codecs="avc1.42C01E" frameRate="25" height="360" id="video/5" scanType="progressive" width="640"/>
        <Representation bandwidth="1033211" codecs="avc1.42C01E" frameRate="25" height="360" id="video/6" scanType="progressive" width="640"/>
        <Representation bandwidth="1545041" codecs="avc1.42C01E" frameRate="25" height="360" id="video/7" scanType="progressive" width="640"/>
      </AdaptationSet>
      <!-- Audio -->
```

Comment: Can you share short example of your mpeg-dash manifest showing part of single representation?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I have edited and added example xml file.

Comment: `SegmentTemplate` is giving you URL template for segments in media part - just replace `RepresentationID` with `id` from `Representation` you are going to use and `Number` with segment you are requesting. The URL is relative to address of your manifest file. Is that what you are struggling with?

Comment: Thanks @LadislavMrnka. Yeah this is what I was struggling with. I am not from media background, so have very little idea about these formats. How do we calculate segment number.. is it calculated based of total duration, segment duration and timescale ? in this case will there be ( 2 * 3600 + 34 * 60 + 47) / (3000/1000) segments for one representation ??